# JavaScript text manipulation as you type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `textarea` where user needs to type something in the specific way but the text that will show in `textarea` needs to be different than the one he is typing in. So basicly I need some kind of function to be called everytime key is pressed. I tryed to do it with `onkeydown`, and `onkeyup` but I without success.

I will give an example to explain it better. "letters-pressed" will be the text which user is really typing, and "letters-showed" are the ones which are displayed in the `textarea`.

> letters-pressed: "Hello, can you please help me with something? It is not that hard"
>   letters-showed: "Hello,, I dont want your help? It is not that hard"

So, what I want is when I press the second "comma" after "Hello", that my text starts showing the pre-scripted text in textarea which will be different than the one I typed in.

And when I use the "questionmark", I want to start showing the real text again. Everything between second "comma" and that "questionmark" must be stored to a variable which I will use after.

```
var hiddenText = ", i dont want your help";
```

UPDATE:
I am close to making it work but currently it works a bit "slow". Letter typed in is firstly showed, and after inputing second letter the first one is being filtered. I need it to be instant, so the function gets called before letter is shown in textarea. I managed it to work by putting strings into an array, and then comparing current letter to the same index letter in pre-scripted string. And if it's the same, leave it, if its different, get letter from pre-scripted string.

```js
function filter() {

// $ufText is unfiltered text which is typed in.
// $psTextArray is pre-scripted text.
// $filtered text is, well, filtered text.

let $ufTextArray = [];
let $psTextArray = [];
let $filteredText = "";

let $ufText = $("#txt").val();
$ufTextArray = $ufText.split('');
console.log($ufTextArray);

let $psText = "Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?Hello, can you please help me with something?";
$psTextArray = $psText.split('');

for (let i=0; i<$ufText.length ; i++) {

   if ($ufTextArray[i] != $psTextArray[i]) {
 
      $filteredText = $filteredText + $psTextArray[i];
      $("#txt").val($filteredText);


  } else {
   
      $filteredText = $filteredText + $ufTextArray[i];
      $("#txt").val($filteredText);   

  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt" cols="80" rows="2" onkeydown="filter()"></textarea>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the user doesn't type a comma, or types "Good morning, ..."? Note that using key events to change the content of the field the user is typing in gets fiddly because you need to keep track of the cursor position in case the user is editing the beginning or middle of an existing string.

Comment: The whole point of it is to type in the text in specific way, so if it isnt properly inputed it won't work which will force user to type what needs to be typed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the textarea

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="testfield1"></textarea>
```

Using jQuery, you can modify the value of the text area using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testfield1').on('keyup paste', function() {
        $('#testfield1').val("some value");
    });
});
```

Let's break this down:

```
$(document).ready(function() { });
```

This is jQuery shorthand for the Document ready function; it means that the script runs after the document is loaded. All the code in the

```
function(){}
```

Part is executed once the document is loaded

```
$('#testfield1').on('keyup paste', function() { });
```

This function uses jQuery selector syntax to grab the textarea out of the DOM. It's assigning an event listener for the "keyup" and "paste" events. Everything within this function is now executed whenever one of those actions happens.

I'll leave it up to you to implement the specifics of what you want your textarea to do, but it should happen within this anonymous function. My example here simple sets the value of the textarea to "some value" any time the event fires, using the selector and the

```
val()
```

function.

See it in action here [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/tgkjbuan/1/)

Comment: Thanks but that won't work for me. I need text to be filtered letter by letter while Inputing. Real time filter. The point is that I know what I am typing but the person standing next to me thinks I am typing something else and that needs to be letter by letter. The problem is that I will never know exactly what will the real input be so I don't know what to filter. What I need is the way to start filtering everything as soon as I type ",," and until I type "?". Everything else is fine. But the filtering needs to happen on every character input.

Comment: Yeah, so like I said, you need to implement your own logic within the event listener; that will fire every time. You can add an argument "e" to the "keyup" listener closure to get the event, and then get the key pressed with e.keyCode() [link](https://jsfiddle.net/tgkjbuan/2/)